# innodb_lock_wait_timeout cant change it

Tags: mariadb, mysql-5.6, ubuntu

I cannot seem to permanatly set innodb_lock_wait_timeout in the sql database I need to change this to 600.

Its for yetiforce crm system. I am running Ubuntu 16.06, with lamp.

Everything else is set bar this but I cannot see it anywhere in my my.cnf file or php.ini.

Even tried global set in the db itself but it wont change.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You might follow the thread from MartinK at:  https://forum.eset.com/topic/7249-simultaneous-connection-count/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in-order to change `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` default value you need to edit you `my.cnf` file and look for `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` if the parameter exist then you need to edit the current value to 600 and restart the service, otherwise you need to add the parameter `innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 600` and restart the service. 
Demo:
my.ini content (I am using windows here, but MySQL) configuration is the same
[image]

Re-staring MySQL service and check if the parameter value changed
[image]

Comment: Do I just copy your data? As my file is blank

Comment: Spot on,. Added innodb_lock_timeout = 600 in my disable strict trans table.